# GraphQL - Execute sub query conditionally

Tags: graphql, react-apollo

I'm trying to optimise the query executed by some of my react components that are shared across the whole app, such as Footer and Header components.

I'm trying not to fetch the Student Solution details when the variable `institutionPath` is not provided.

```
query organisationAndInstitution($organisationName: String!, $institutionPath: String!, $fetchInstitution: Boolean!){
    organisation(where: {
      name: $organisationName
    }){
      name
    }

    studentSolutionRelationships(where:{ 
      AND: [
        {
          status: PUBLISHED
        },
        {
          studentSolution: {
            status: PUBLISHED
          }
        }
      ]
    }) @include(if: $fetchInstitution) {
      status
  }
}
```

To do so, I added a `fetchInstitution` boolean variable and added the `@include(if: $fetchInstitution)` directive.

But directives seem to apply only on fields, not on whole queries. So I wonder if what I want to do is possible, because the way I wrote it is invalid.

Comment: `studentSolutionRelationships` and `organisation` are still fields, they just happen to be fields on the query root operation type. There's nothing incorrect about your approach. When you say it's "invalid", what do you mean? What error are you seeing?

Comment: FWIW, I see a missing closing bracket, but that could just be a typo here and not in your code.

Comment: When I try to execute this, the query hangs and eventually times out. I'm not using my own graphql server but a third party, so maybe this kind of things isn't implemented on their backend. But I didn't debug it much since I thought I wasn't doing it right, I'll take a deeper look. Thanks! (and the typo is because I removed lots of noise here, to focus on what matters)

Comment: And indeed you were right. The query works well on graphiql but was failing from my source code, I guess it was either not properly translated, or I made a mistake in the code. Either way, it seems to be the correct way of fetching optional fields!

Comment: It was indeed a dumb mistake in my code (not providing the new variable for all the calls using this query). If you want to write a proper response I'll accept it and close the issue :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any field in a GraphQL document can be explicitly *included* using the `@include` directive or explicitly *excluded* using the `@skip` directive. The directive should be provided after the field name and arguments, but before the field's selection set, if it has one, as shown in your question:

```
studentSolutionRelationships(where:{ 
  #...input fields omitted for brevity
}) @include(if: $fetchInstitution) {
  status
}
```

The directive takes a single argument (`if`) which must be a `Boolean` value. This value may be a literal (i.e. `true` or `false`) or a variable of the `Boolean` type. GraphQL does not provide a way to evaluate expressions -- any conditional logic has to be reside in the client code and be used to determine the value of the variable passed to the `if` argument.

The directives may be applied to *any* field in a document, including root-level ones like `studentSolutionRelationships` and `organisation` in the question. In fact, you can exclude all root fields using these directives -- just keep in mind that in such a scenario, the query will still run and just return an empty object.

In other words, your approach here is correct. If the query is failing, it's because of an unrelated issue.